# string array split - string[] to string error

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to split a `string` (`input`)

```
"1#Artikel1|ArtikelN$2#Artikel1|Artikel2|ArtikelN$3#ArtikelN"
```

into a `List<string>` (`liste`) with expected result (simplified)

```
{
 "Artikel1 , ArtikelN",
 "Artikel1 , Artikel2 , ArtikelN",
 "ArtikelN" 
}
```

but I am getting the **compile time error** in the process:

> cannot convert string[] to string

```
private List<Data> GetData(string input)
{
    List<Data> liste = new List<Data>();
    foreach (string section in input.Split('$'))
    {
        String[] tab = section.Split('#');
        String[] parties = new string[20];
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 1; j < tab.Length; j++)
        { 
            parties[i] =tab[j].Split('|'); <- ERROR HERE 
            i++;
        };
        liste.Add(new Data(// insert data));
    }
    return liste;
}
```

How can I solve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some *examples* of the initial strings and the desired *outcome*?

Comment: Your `parties[i]` is `string`, but `tab[j].Split('|')` is `string[]`

Comment: this goes in :"1#Artikel1|ArtikelN$2#Artikel1|Artikel2|ArtikelN$3#ArtikelN" 
and i want : Artikel1 , ArtikelN in the parties array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you right (please, see comments),

> i want : `Artikel1 , Artikel` in the parties array

You want to `Split` and then `Join` articles within chapter (let's put it like this) i.e.

```
  string input = @"1#Artikel1|ArtikelN$2#Artikel1|Artikel2|ArtikelN$3#ArtikelN";

  List<string> liste = input
    .Split('$')                                 // split into chapters
    .Select(chapter => chapter                  // for each chapter:   
       .Substring(chapter.IndexOf('#') + 1)     //   get rid of 1#, 2# etc. prefix
       .Split('|'))                             //   Split by |  
    .Select(items => string.Join(" , ", items)) //   Join back by " , "
    .ToList();
```

Let's have a look

```
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, liste));
```

Outcome:

```
  Artikel1 , ArtikelN
  Artikel1 , Artikel2 , ArtikelN
  ArtikelN
```

Comment: @Adri1511: I've edited your question, please, have a look at it and correct me if I'm not right in details

Answer (score 2):

This line `tab[j].Split('|')` would split the string in `tab[j]` in an array of strings based on the delimiter `|`. So you can't assign the result of this call to
`parties[i]`, whose type is string.